# Power loss in gate driver independent of duty cycle?

Tags: power, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, mosfet-driver

> Inside a generic switch mode power supply a MOSFET is used. The switching frequency is \$f_{sw} = 300\text{kHz}\$ and the duty cycle is \$D=0.45\$.
>
> To drive the gate of a MOSFET, we use a gate driver with output voltage \$V_g =12 \text{V}\$. The charge on the gate of the MOSFET is \$Q_g = 25\text{nC}\$.
>
> What is the average power loss in the gate driver?

**My attempt**

From this [application journal](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt664/slyt664.pdf) we get a formula: -

[image]

Inserting values gives me a power loss of \$P_{loss} =25 \cdot 10^{-9}\text{C} \cdot 12\text{V} \cdot 300 \cdot 10^3\text{Hz} =0.09\text{W}\$

That was pretty easy to calculate, but is this really true? Doesn't the power loss depend on the duty cycle at all, and only on the switching frequency? Is the duty cycle included in the question just to throw me off?

Comment: If one look at a IRF540, what would be taken into account for Qg? 72 nC -> 0.26 W?

Comment: Gate power is only supplied at the transition. The gate, once fully charged, consumes almost (DC leakage) zero power. Hence, duty cycle doesn't come in to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all boils down to some very simple calculation, assuming charge conservation, we have a Qtot charge moved form Vcc power supply to gate at each MOSFET turn-on.

This, according to voltage definition, takes an
$$\Delta E= V_\mathrm{CC}\;Q_\mathrm{tot}$$
energy at each turn-on.

Note that no assumption is taken regarding the gate driver resistence nor the linearity of the capacitance modelling the gate.

Some of this energy is stored in this capacitance while the remaining fraction is torched in the gate driver resistance and driver switch (transistor).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNxAjD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We actually do not care about the two energies values since in any case whatever was still stored in the gate capacitance is dissipated in the gate driver at switch-off.

So next cycle will start from null initial conditions and take the same \$\Delta E\$ energy from the power supply.

So if this is repeated fsw times in a second the average power taken from Vcc supply is
$$P=f_\mathrm{SW}\Delta E= f_\mathrm{SW}\;V_\mathrm{CC}\;Q_\mathrm{tot} $$

which is QED.

Answer (score 1):

The result is not surprising.

The power loss in a MOSFET driver (or any RC circuit switched way slower than its characteristic time) happens only when the state is changed.

How much the state is changed is the operating frequency (twice, but 2 is a constant).

How much the circuit happens to spend in any of the 2 states is irrelevant because there is no current or power flow - as long as it is long enough for the RC to settle in the new state.

In a practical switched MOSFET it should always be kept long enough.